# Golang waiter implementation pattern

Tags: go

I'm working on a simple waiter implementation, waiter - is a code that polls an external API until a desired response is received within a given period of time. I would like to keep it simple, but at the same time write it in the native Golang style. At the moment I come up with the following code (the actual API request is removed for brevity). I'm not entirely sure if the combination of a ticker and `time.After` is the right approach to achieve this, while it seems to be working as expected. I feel like there should be a common pattern for doing this.

````
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    tickerDone := make(chan bool, 1)
    timeoutDone := make(chan bool, 1)
    go func() {
        defer ticker.Stop()
        i := 1
        for {
            select {
            case <-tickerDone:
                fmt.Println("Stopping the ticker")
                timeoutDone <- true
                return
            case t := <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
                if i == 3 {
                    fmt.Println("It's a 3rd tick, enought")
                    ticker.Stop()
                    tickerDone <- true
                }

                i += 1
            }
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-timeoutDone:
        fmt.Println("Completed before the timeout")
    case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("Timed out")
        ticker.Stop()
        tickerDone <- true
    }

}

```
````

Answer (score 2):

For this example it's important to know whether calling the API blocks until a value is ready, or returns quickly with some sort of "not ready" indication.

If it's a blocking call, does it accept a [context.Context](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context) argument?

If so, then all you need to do is this:

```golang
func main() {
  ctx := context.Background()
  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*time.Second)
  defer cancel()

  val, err := callAPI(ctx, ...)
  if err != nil {
    // ...handle error, which can include context.DeadlineExceeded...
  }

  // ...val is the result from the API...
}
```

Generally speaking, context objects are the best way to implement timeouts and cancellation.

If the API is a blocking function that does not take a context argument, then I suggest wrapping it so that it does:

```golang
func myAPIWrapper(ctx context.Context, ...) (val apiValType, err error) {
  done := make(chan struct{})
  go func() {
    val, err = callAPI(...)
    close(done)
  }()

  select {
  case <-ctx.Done():
    // Context timed out or was canceled, return its error.
    return val, ctx.Err()

  case <-done:
    // API call completed.
    return val, err
  }
}
```

Finally, if the API is a non-blocking function that you have to call repeatedly, then I suggest wrapping that as follows (using a `time.Ticker` as you proposed). In all cases the idea is to present a cancelable, blocking function to `main` (or whatever has to call this):

````golang
func myAPIWrapper(ctx context.Context, ...) (val apiValType, err error) {
  done := make(chan struct{})
  go func() {
    defer close(done)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
      // Don't wait for the ticker to fire before calling the API.
      var valReady bool
      val, valReady, err = callAPI(...)
      if err != nil || valReady {
        return
      }
      select {
      case <-ctx.Done():
        err = ctx.Err()
        return

      case <-ticker.C:
        // Do nothing here, just loop again.
      }
    }
  }()

  <-done
  return val, err
}
```
````